# Trouble inserting data into a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I am developing a desktop application in Netbeans. I am trying to insert a record into database. The very strange problem I am having is that when I press the save button no error occurs, everything works perfect. But when I check my DB, there is no data in there. But when I try to insert data directly in **phpmyadmin** through query then it inserts the record after the `ID` (auto increment) that has been generated before when I try to save data through desktop app. I know It is difficult to explain. Let me give you all a bit more explanation

For example my database is all clear and I am trying to save my first record

1. Through desktop app I pressed the save button
2. when I checked the database there is no record there

Here above If data was saved successfully then the record ID has to be 1

1. But now I am inserting the record by going into phpmyadmin and manually typing the quering in sql tab
2. now the `id` of the record should be 1 but the id is 2.

So it means through desktop app data is saving but somewhere hidden which I can't see and also It is remembering the id. I hope you undertstand my question.

If I pressed save button 3 times  after then I insert some data in phpmyadmin the id of that record is 4.

I don't know what the problem is?

Here is my code :

```
    public class DBConnectionManager {

    private static String DRIVER_NAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String HOST_NAME = "localhost";
    private static String PORT_NUMBER = "3306";
    private static String DB_NAME = "sales";
    private static String USER_NAME = "root";
    private static String PASSWORD = "";

        public static Connection openConnection() throws Exception {

            Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);

            String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://"+HOST_NAME+":"+PORT_NUMBER+"/"+DB_NAME;

            Connection connection =   DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,USER_NAME,PASSWORD);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);    
            return connection;
       }
    }

   public void addSupplierDetail() {

        String contact_name = txt_contactName.getText();
        String shop_name = txt_shopName.getText();
        String city = txt_city.getText();
        int phone = Integer.parseInt(txt_phone.getText());
        int mobileNo = Integer.parseInt(txt_mobile.getText());
        String address = txt_address.getText();

        Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
        supplier.setContactName(contact_name);
        supplier.setShopName(shop_name);
        supplier.setCity(city);
        supplier.setPhone(phone);
        supplier.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
        supplier.setAddress(address);


        connection = DBConnectionManager.openConnection();
        SupplierDAO dao = new SupplierDAO(connection);
        try {

            if (dao.addSupplier(supplier)) {

                connection.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data save");
                // Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                //dashboard.setVisible(true);

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "not saved");

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }


    }       

        public boolean addSupplier(Supplier supplier) throws Exception {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO suppliers"
                + "(sup_name,sup_address,city,mobile_no,phone,shop_name)"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                ps.setString(1, supplier.getContactName());
                ps.setString(2, supplier.getAddress());
                ps.setString(3, supplier.getCity());
                ps.setInt(4, supplier.getMobileNo());
                ps.setInt(5, supplier.getPhone());
            ps.setString(6, supplier.getShopName());
            System.out.println(ps);
            int rowscount = ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("no of rows updated: " + rowscount);
            ps.close();    
            return rowscount > 0;

    }
```

Comment: [1] check how your code is committing to the DB and [2] post a stacktrace if any

Comment: @Leo Are you asking me to show code how I am connecting to db ?

Comment: user1, this place is to understand problems not to debug your code. You must google and find answers too, Leo told you about committing to DB the key word is autocommit, so you have to Google "jdbc autocommit" and learn things by your self, we can give you directions more than answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the debugger, if everything is executed as expected, check the `autoCommit` property of your statement (or connection I forgot to which one it is bound)

Answer (score 0):

Since the auto-increment seems to be happening, as you said. Looks like auto commit is set to false. You can try to set it at connection level, by calling `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` or you can do it only for that transaction by calling `connection.commit()`.